# Video freezes while moving

Tags: jquery, dialog, freeze

I have an `iframe` element whose `src` is an embedded JW player. This iframe in a jQuery dialog. Normally the video plays well, but the video is freezing when while I resize or move the dialog window with my mouse.

Is there any way to prevent the video from freezing?

Comment: The browser may not render the frames of the video while it's being moved around the screen for performance reasons. This is standard behaviour and there's nothing you can do to change it. Note that the same thing happens on Youtube when toggling between the small and large player.

Comment: thanks for clarification.

Comment: No problem. I added it as an answer for you as 'No' is technically still an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser may not render the frames of the video while it's being moved around the screen for performance reasons. This is standard behaviour and there's nothing you can do to change it.

Note that the same thing happens on Youtube when toggling between the small and large player.